# How to set CLASSPATH environment variable to working directory? (Linux)

Tags: java, linux, classpath

I was wondering how it's possible to add the current directory to CLASSPATH.

Say if I cd into a folder /src/, if I want to add src/ itself to CLASSPATH how would I do this within the folder src?

I know I can do it with absolute paths, but how do I do it with relative paths?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on *sh try:

```
export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH
```

or on csh try:

```
setenv CLASSPATH .:$CLASSPATH
```

It should take care CLASSPATH from current directory perspective.